on subgraphs of the hypercube
I'm reading this paper and I'm stuck on the proof of Lemma 4.2 (in particular, Claim 4.3). They define $G$ to be a subgraph of the hypercube $Q_n$ with exactly half the vertices, i.e. $2^{n-1}$ vertices. Fix a direction $i \in [n]$ and let $x^{(i)}$ denote the $n$-bit vertex $x$ with its $i$-th bit flipped. Consider the following sets:
$X_i =\{x \in V(G): x^{(i)} \in V(G)\}$, $Y_i = \{y \notin V(G): y^{(i)} \notin V(G)\}$, and $A_i = V(Q_n)\setminus (X_i \cup Y_i)$. They then argue that:

I am struggling to understand Claim 4.3. Since $x$ is already adjacent to $x^{(i)}$ how can it have more than $\Delta-1$ neighbours in $A_i$? Are they considering $x$ as the pair $(x, x^{(i)})$ and counting for both of them? In the next line why are they not counting the neighbour $x^{(i)}$ when they argue that at least $(n-2\Delta +1)$ neighbours are in $Y_i$?
Some help would be appreciated!

They are counting $x^{(i)}$ when they argue that at least $n-2\Delta+1$ neighbors are in $Y_i$; that's why they get $n-2\Delta+1$ and not $n-2\Delta+2$. But I don't see why they are so certain that $x$ cannot have any other neighbors in $X_i$.

Sorry, maybe I'm missing something glaringly obvious but wouldn't the number of neighbours of $x$ outside $A_i$ be at most $(n-1)- 2\Delta+2 = n-2\Delta +1$? They're saying all that's in $Y_i$. I agree with your comment about having other neighbors in $X_i$, I don't see that either.

Why are you subtracting from $n-1$? In $Q_n$, $x$ has degree $n$, so there are $n-2\Delta+2$ neighbors outside $A_i$, and $n-2\Delta+1$ of them that are not $x^{(i)}$.

@MishaLavrov thanks, I'm so used to working with n as the 'total number of vertices' I missed that simple thing. As for the neighbours in $X_i$, I think the statement of the claim can be rephrased to say $x$ has at most $(2\Delta-2)$ neighbours in $(X_i \cup A_i) \setminus {x^{(i)}}$. The extra factor of 2 is not required when dealing with neighbours in $X_i$.

Here "neighbours" is talking about neighbours in the hypercube. Some (at most $\Delta$) neighbours of $x$ are also in $G$, and some neighbours are in $A_i$, but since there are vertices in $A_i$ not in $V(G)$, $x$ could potentially have more than $\Delta$ neighbours in $A_i$.
What the proof is saying is that we can divide the neighbours of $x$ in $A_i$ into two sets. The first set is those neighbours that are also in $V(G)$. There are at most $\Delta-1$ of them, since $x^{(i)}$ is in $V(G)$ but not in $A_i$. The second set is those neighbours in $A_i$ that are not also in $V(G)$. Now for every such neighbour of $x$, there is a neighbour of $x^{(i)}$, different from $x$, that is in $G$ (by flipping bit $i$), and since there are only $\Delta-1$ neighbours of $x^{(i)}$ in $G$, there are at most $\Delta-1$ neighbours of $x$ in the second set.

Ah that makes more sense. But when they count neighbours in $Y_i$ in the final step, why don't they consider the neighbours of $x$ in $X_i$? We know there's at least one neighbour there.

@kleinbottle Indeed, they seem to be assuming there is exactly one neighbour there (which is why they get $n-2\Delta+1$ rather than $n-2\Delta+2$). I don't see why that should be the case, though.

I think the statement of the claim can be rephrased to say $x$ has at most $2\Delta -2$ neighbours in $X_i \cup A_i$. This follows from the same reasoning you suggested.  Then it would make sense for the rest of the neighbours to be in $Y_i$
